# SQL: sum 3 columns when one column has a null value?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    sum(TotalHoursM)
          + (TotalHoursT)
          + (TotalHoursW)
          + (TotalHoursTH)
          + (TotalHoursF) 
          AS TOTAL
FROM LeaveRequest
```

Comment: `SQL Server` not tagged ?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

If the column has a 0 value, you are fine, my guess is that you have a problem with a Null value, in that case you would need to use `IsNull(Column, 0)` to ensure it is always 0 at minimum.

Comment: Yonita is Michael's answer answered your question mark it as answered by using the check mark.

Comment: "Yonita is Michael's answer answered your question mark it as answered by using the check mark" -- my brain took an age to parse this sentence.

Comment: In MySQL, ISNULL seems to be just a 1-parameter boolean function, but as in omkarv's answer, IFNULL does the job.

Comment: `IsNull` is not portable, and the question doesn't specify a database. See below for `COALESCE`, which is portable (if not always optimal in performance).

Comment: The question is on SQL, but the IsNull function indicated is not an SQL primitive.

Comment: Thanks but Mysql needs to use ```IFNULL``` instead.

Answer (score 97):

The previous answers using the `ISNULL` function are correct only for MS Sql Server.  The `COALESCE` function will also work in SQL Server.  But will also work in standard SQL database systems.  In the given example:

```
SELECT sum(COALESCE(TotalHoursM,0))
          + COALESCE(TotalHoursT,0)
          + COALESCE(TotalHoursW,0)
          + COALESCE(TotalHoursTH,0)
          + COALESCE(TotalHoursF,0) AS TOTAL FROM LeaveRequest
```

This is identical to the `ISNULL` solution with the only difference being the name of the function.  Both work in SQL Server but, `COALESCE` is ANSI standard and `ISNULL` is not.  Also, `COALESCE` is more flexible.
`ISNULL` will only work with two parameters.  If the first parameter is NULL then the value of the second parameter is returned, else the value of the first is returned.
COALESCE will take 2 to 'n' (I don't know the limit of 'n') parameters and return the value of the first parameter that is not `NULL`.  When there are only two parameters the effect is the same as `ISNULL`.

Comment: Additionally, Oracle SQL does not have ISNULL. Though, in my experience, you may get better results with NVL(): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm

Comment: Just the one i was looking for - postgres doesn't have isnull ether.

Comment: Isnull didn't work as expected in MySQL. Coalesce did the job. Thanks.

Comment: IsNull is not a SQL primitive. Therefore the other answers are not correct, only this one.

Comment: `ISNULL` ***vs*** `COALESCE` ?

Answer (score 17):

```
SELECT sum(isnull(TotalHoursM,0)) 
         + isnull(TotalHoursT,0) 
         + isnull(TotalHoursW,0) 
         + isnull(TotalHoursTH,0) 
         + isnull(TotalHoursF,0))
AS TOTAL FROM LeaveRequest
```

Answer (score 7):

[Just for reference, the equivalent statement for MySQL is: IFNull(Column,0)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).

This statement evaluates as the column value if not null, otherwise it is evaluated as 0.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ISNULL`:

```
ISNULL(field, VALUEINCASEOFNULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

looks like you want to SUM all the columns (I'm not sure where "sum 3 columns" comes from), not just TotalHoursM, so try this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(    ISNULL(TotalHoursM  ,0)
          + ISNULL(TotalHoursT  ,0)
          + ISNULL(TotalHoursW  ,0)
          + ISNULL(TotalHoursTH ,0)
          + ISNULL(TotalHoursF  ,0) 
       ) AS TOTAL
    FROM LeaveRequest
```

Comment: thanks for the down vote almost 8 years after answering this! ha ha, this is the exact same answer given by others on this very question.  I answered before them, yet they have lots of up votes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `nvl(Column,0)`

Comment: nvl is specific to oracle pl/sql.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
select sum (case when TotalHousM is null then 0 else TotalHousM end)
       + (case when TotalHousT is null then 0 else TotalHousT end)
       + (case when TotalHousW is null then 0 else TotalHousW end)
       + (case when TotalHousTH is null then 0 else TotalHousTH end)
       + (case when TotalHousF is null then 0 else TotalHousF end)
       as Total
From LeaveRequest
```

Comment: However I like this solution because it would also be able to take care of those cases where the value is blank and not NULL. You would have to add the LEN() > 0.

Comment: What is the difference between "being blank" and "NULL"? Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to avoid the null value use IsNull(Column, 1)

Comment: `IsNull(Column, 1)` will give wrong results. It will increase the sum / total by 1 for every null value.