# I want to group data from a SQL Server database into hourly report

Tags: sql-server

I would like to ask the community the following:

I have a table `Productivity` with the following columns:

```
SerialNumber (Primary Key) - Identity Column
Processed_Time_Stamp - DateTime
Login_ID - nvarchar(255)
Order_Number - Float
Order_Location - Float
Status - nvarchar(255)
```

I am using this query:

```
SELECT 
    Login_ID, COUNT(Login_ID) as [Total Number]
FROM 
    Productivity
WHERE 
    Processed_Time_Stamp >= '2014-12-03 10:30:00.000' 
    AND Processed_Time_Stamp <= '2014-12-04 10:30:00.000'
GROUP BY 
    Login_ID
```

This gives me these results:

```
Login_ID    Total Number
------------------------
Zohaib          10
XYX             20
```

However, I want to break this up in the following format:

```
Login_ID   10 AM   11 AM
-------------------------
zohaib       5       5
XYZ          7      13
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: To get the hour, you just use datepart:  `datepart(HOUR,Processed_Time_Stamp)`.  To present the data like you want, you'll need to `pivot` the data.  Search for that here, there's tons of questions about pivoting.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response Andrew. It will be a great help if you could provide me a link to any good post on 'pivot the data'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
WITH DATA
AS
(
SELECT Login_ID, 1 AS N, DATEPART(HOUR, Processed_Time_Stamp) H
FROM Productivity
WHERE Processed_Time_Stamp >='2014-12-03 10:30:00.000' and Processed_Time_Stamp <= '2014-12-04 10:30:00.000'
)
SELECT Login_ID, [10], [11]
FROM DATA
PIVOT (SUM(N) FOR H IN ([10], [11])) AS P
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much King.code. This is exactly what I wanted. I need a further help. I want to show the 'NULL' as 0.

Comment: Any workaround for converting the 'NULL' results to 0?

Comment: `COALESCE(YourColumn, 0)`

Comment: This was impressive my friend. I changed the query to "COALESCE([10],0) as [10 AM]" and it worked like charm.

Comment: How can we add a Total Column at the end to show the Total Productivity?

Comment: Just wrap the last select like this: `SELECT Login_ID, [10], [11], [10] + [11] FROM (SELECT Login_ID, [10], [11]
FROM DATA
PIVOT (SUM(N) FOR H IN ([10], [11])) AS P) AS PP`

Comment: Remeber to accept the answer that helped you solve the problem.

Comment: Your answers have enormously helped me. I am sorry, I am new to the forum so I don't know to accept an answer. I have Clicked the Check Box Under 1. Is that all I need to do to accept an answer?

Comment: Hi king.code,

When I am trying to add the values in the columns the result is null if the columns with '0' values are used. Please Help?

Comment: I didn't understand, could you exaplain a little more?

Comment: Thanks king.code. I got it fixed from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088648/sql-sum-3-columns-when-one-column-has-a-null-value