# SQL sum different columns into one statement

Tags: sql

I am building an application that uses a SQL statement to sum three columns. Below is a sample table:

```
Table1
column1     column2  column3
NULL        30.00    NULL
60.00       NULL     NULL
NULL        10.00    NULL
NULL        NULL     15.00
```

I want to sum column1, column2, and column3 into one statement. I want the result to be `115.00 (30.00 + 60.00 + 10.00 + 15.00)`. The table can have data in one of the three columns, but never in any two.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT ISNULL(sum(column1),ISNULL(sum(column2),sum(column3)) as amount FROM Table1
```

The result is something not remotely close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: sum 3 columns when one column has a null value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088648/sql-sum-3-columns-when-one-column-has-a-null-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can do:

```
select sum(column1) + sum(column2) + sum(column3)
from table1 t;
```

Because each column has at least one value, the individual sums will not be `NULL`, so this will give the expected value.

To be safe, you *could* use `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(sum(column1), 0) + coalesce(sum(column2), 0) + coalesce(sum(column3), 0)
from table1 t;
```

Answer (score 2):

The COALESCE function will also work. In the given example:

```
SELECT sum(COALESCE(column1,0))
          + COALESCE(column2,0)
          + COALESCE(column3,0)
    AS TOTAL FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `coalesce` to assign `0` when there is `null` in the column and then sum the values.

```
SELECT SUM(coalesce(column1,0)+coalesce(column2,0)+coalesce(column3,0)) as amount 
FROM Table1
```