# SQL sum not exist items between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables, and Table1, Table2 and Table3 all have columns `Itemcode` and `Qty`.

I want write a query all itemcode from all tables with sum qty, but some items do not match both tables.

When I tried to write query with

```
sum(tn2.sales + via1.sales + bcg.sales)
```

I'm getting blank values.

Comment: `+NULL` will return `NULL`. wrap each column that could have a value of `NULL` with either a `COALESCE` or `ISNULL`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to illustrate your issue.

Comment: probable dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088648/sql-sum-3-columns-when-one-column-has-a-null-value

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a 'view' of the tables and sum up the values as per your query

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more elegant solution, but here is a quick way. Build three selects with unions and then sum that subquery up.

```
select all_items.itemcode, all_items.Qty, sum(all_items.sales) from 
  (Select itemcode, Qty, sum(sales)as sales from tn2 group by itemcode
  union
  Select itemcode, Qty, sum(sales) as sales from via1 group by itemcode
  union
  Select itemcode, Qty, sum(sales)as sales from bcg group by itemcode) all_items
group by all_items.itemcode, all_items.Qty
```